# String Replace a word that is between special characters

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

```
$text_string = "One One One,One.One OneTwo, Onetwo .Onetwo TwoOne One";
```

I want to replace the word "One" with "Three" which is alone or between special characters or at the beginning/ending of the string.
Have anybody an idea?

The result must be:

```
$text_string = "Three Three Three,Three.Three OneTwo, Onetwo .Onetwo TwoOne Three";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\b` to check for word boundaries:

```
$str = 'One One One,One.One OneTwo, Onetwo .Onetwo';
$replaced = preg_replace('/\bOne\b/', 'Three', $str);
echo $replaced; // Three Three Three,Three.Three OneTwo, Onetwo .Onetwo TwoOne Three
```

Comment: this is case sensitive now?

Comment: If you want it to be, add an `i` behind the regex: `/\\bOne\\b/i`

Comment: why do you put `\\b`, instead of just `\b` - see https://regex101.com/r/O7C3cl/1

Comment: c'n'p error, thanks

Comment: cant replace a word contains Ü,Ä,Ö with this

`$returnValue = preg_replace('/\bÜber\b/i', 'Three', 'One Über One,One.Über one OneTwo, Onetwo .Onetwo TwoOne Über', -1);`

Comment: have it! `setlocale();`